# IOCP With WSASend and OVERLAPPED pool

Tags: sockets, iocp

This is a server with sockets using IOCP.
I initalize a pool of OVERLAPPED which i use to send WSASend() calls.
Every WSASend() call take out a single OVERLAPPED pointer out of the pool and puts it back in IOCP worker thread on notification.

However, when a client dissconnect, *SOME* of the pending WSASend() calls gets dropped and therefor i have no chance to recycle the OVERLAPPED pointers that were taken out of the pool.

How can i cancel 100% all the pending WSASend() calls while making sure that they wont get to the IOCP worker, so i can manually recycle the OVERLAPPED pointers on disconnection?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that the IOCP callback is **not** called with a failure code if a client disconnects while an overlapped send is in progress?

Comment: Closing the socket should abort any send/recv in progress. Are you closing the socket when you detect the disconnect? Worse case, you could just wrap your `OVERLAPPED` struct (you really should be using `WSAOVERLAPPED`, BTW) in a `struct` that also contains the original `SOCKET`, that way when a disconnect occurs you can loop through your items that are in progress looking for the disconnected `SOCKET` and then you will know which items can be recycled.

Comment: Yes it is inheritted, anyway, I want to be sure that when calling closesocket(s), all the pending WSASend() calls will not be posted to the IOCP.
If i can make sure of that, i can recycle all the OVERLAPPED pointers manually without worrying of recycling them twice.

Comment: Between the time the client disconnects and the time you close that socket, are you allowing the thread to enter an alertable state so the IOCP callback can be called? Otherwise, if you go the `struct` approach, you can add a `bool` to it to flag when it is in the pool, then you can check that value when deciding whether to recycle or not.

Comment: Yes, i could do that, but how can i know that after calling closesocket() and after recycling all the saved structs, how can i know that IOCP wont receive those WSASend() copmletion notifications? Sounds like a race condition to me and i have to make sure they won't get to the IOCP worker 100000%.
How can i make sure of that?

Comment: The structs will be flagged, so the IOCP can check for that in case it does get called after recycling occurs. And it is not a race since you control when the IOCP thread(s) enter an alertable state so IOCP callbacks can be called, so just don't go into an alertable state while recycling the structs of a closed socket. Now granted, this all hinges on the assumption that IOCP callbacks are not being called on disconnect, which I think they should be and you have not disputed yet.

Comment: This in theory does not guarantee that again, the pending WSASend() calls will indeed get posted anyway after disconnecting and recycling.

Comment: Yes, putting a flag in the structs in order to not recycle them twice would help, but what if in the middle of these 2 situation, another WSASend() call get called and takes that specific struct i just recycled out of the pool, and right after this the WSASend() call from the disconnected get processed by the IOCP worker and gets recycled, the flag has been reset by the new WSASend() call... this is what i meant by race condition.

Comment: There is completely no way in preventing this unless Windows API provides a way of cancelling ALL THE PENDING IO of the socket and be 100% sure that they wont get posted to the IOCP later on, then recycling the structs will be easy and no more worries.

Comment: Have you tried `CancelIo/Ex()` yet?

Answer (score 2):

That's not how IOCPs work.

If you have pending operations that you want to cancel then close the corresponding socket and the operations will either complete or fail and all of the completions (including the failures) will come out of the IOCP eventually.

You need to wait for that to occur and once it has then you are good to shut down.

What I tend to do is have a 'per connection' structure which contains the socket and which is used as the completion key. I then have "per operation" structures which include the `OVERLAPPED` and which also include details of which operation type, the I/O buffer used and other stuff. Both of these structures is reference counted.

When an operation is initiated you increment the reference count on both the connection object and the operation object. When you get a completion you process it and then decrement the counts. When the counts reach 0 you're not doing any work with the objects and they can be recycled to the pool for reuse.

To aid in clean shutdown I have a counter that I can wait on that tracks the number of 'active' 'per connection' objects (sockets).

To shut down you abort all connections and then wait for the connection counter to hit zero. At that point all of your objects are either destroyed or in your pools and you can clean up.

I have some example code, [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html), which is a set of full featured IOCP server examples which may help - it's working code that you can step through and get ideas from if nothing else.

Comment: The reference counter is per-OVERLAPPED structure, I mean, every OVERLAPPED structure must have its own, and it must be atomic, since IOCP works with multiple threads, right? My concern was about that incrementing/decrementing many atomic counters too much times could impact performance, and threads' scalability. May this happen, or its just a baseless worry?

Comment: It can do, and it can be worse on NUMA hardware; as always, profile and see. I'm adjusting my framework at the moment so that we don't use the ref count during actual IOCP dispatch (i.e. in normal operations there is no need to ref count as much as we were). I'm still keeping it as it makes for efficient server design when you want to keep the buffers around for longer than just a single IOCP operation, but for simpler servers (read, parse message, write response over inbound message, reply) there's no ref manipulation at all any more.